# DAG does not trigger from the console

Tags: python, bash, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have been trying create a sample DAG. Test works well with the command line but when I trigger the same DAG from the console, it stay in running state forever. Here is the code below for reference. Help will be really appreciated. I really do not understand for getting stuck in running state. Also airflow scheduler does not show any output when I trigger the dag manually from the console.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.hooks import HttpHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'flow',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

node_bash = """
pwd
"""


t1 = SSHOperator(
     ssh_conn_id='datalakefs',
     task_id='loadfstodb',
     command=node_bash,
     dag=dag)

t1
```

And here is the output from the test command.

```
sudo airflow test flow loadfstodb 28-02-2020
[2020-02-28 10:50:53,602] {settings.py:254} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=13429
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,090] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,090] {dagbag.py:403} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/dag
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:439: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'HttpHook' directly from 'airflow.hooks' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.hooks.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:439: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'PostgresHook' directly from 'airflow.hooks' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.hooks.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,354] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: flow.loadfstodb 2020-02-28T00:00:00+00:00 [None]>
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,368] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: flow.loadfstodb 2020-02-28T00:00:00+00:00 [None]>
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,369] {taskinstance.py:866} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,369] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,369] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,371] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(SSHOperator): loadfstodb> on 2020-02-28T00:00:00+00:00
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,390] {ssh_operator.py:92} INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,421] {base_hook.py:84} INFO - Using connection to: id: datalakefs. Host: datalake, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: airflow, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,422] {ssh_hook.py:166} WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,424] {ssh_hook.py:170} WARNING - No Host Key Verification. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,431] {transport.py:1572} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.6p1)
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,543] {transport.py:1572} INFO - Authentication (publickey) successful!
[2020-02-28 10:50:54,543] {ssh_operator.py:109} INFO - Running command:
pwd
[2020-02-28 10:50:55,760] {ssh_operator.py:143} INFO - /home/airflow
```

Comment: probably try changing node_bash to node_bash = 'pwd'

Comment: Does not work with that too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the airflow scheduler updates its dags by an interval.And it needs some time to wait before the scheduler is aware of the new dag's join.

And because of the initial run it was stuck forever, because of an entry in "job" table of postgres. Then I had to delete the particular entry related to Job and I started my DAG again. And it worked.